# IONIC 4: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'

Tags: gradle, ionic4

**Ionic build failed:**

tried so many solution but end up with same problem:

ionic cordova run android

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.support:support-annotations:27.+.
Required by:
  project :app
> Could not resolve com.android.support:support-annotations:27.+.
  > Failed to list versions for com.android.support:support-annotations.
     > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/support-annotations/maven-metadata.xml.
        > Could not HEAD 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/support-annotations/maven-metadata.xml'.
           > No route to host (Host unreachable)
```

gradle version: 5.2.1

ionic version: 4

Comment: problem fixed. My network does not allow required url.

Comment: I have the same issue, I had tried VPN but still not working